# Yield in a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, iterator, directory-structure, yield

I am trying to do something to all the files under a given path. I don't want to collect all the file names beforehand then do something with them, so I tried this:

```
import os
import stat

def explore(p):
  s = ''
  list = os.listdir(p)
  for a in list:
    path = p + '/' + a
    stat_info = os.lstat(path )
    if stat.S_ISDIR(stat_info.st_mode):
     explore(path)
    else:
      yield path

if __name__ == "__main__":
  for x in explore('.'):
    print '-->', x
```

But this code skips over directories when it hits them, instead of yielding their contents. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Some languages can yield an entire sequence, not just individual elements. I do not think Python is one of them. http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2011/02/28/recursive-iterators-in-f/

Comment: Since the title suggests a more general problem than can be solved by os.walk, consider this:  
  
    def explore(p):  
        if isinstance(p, (list, tuple)):  
            for x in p:  
                explore(p)  
        else:  
            yield p  
  
This has the same problem. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk) instead of reinventing the wheel.

In particular, following the examples in the library documentation, here is an untested attempt:

```
import os
from os.path import join

def hellothere(somepath):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(somepath):
        for curfile in files:
            yield join(root, curfile)


# call and get full list of results:
allfiles = [ x for x in hellothere("...") ]

# iterate over results lazily:
for x in hellothere("..."):
    print x
```

Comment: Giving working code is good, but explaining what the OP did wrong, especially when they ask for that, is even better.

Comment: the question is about yield and recursion and not about best way to implement the os.walk

Comment: also : in Python 2 walk is slower then listdir, see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/

Answer (score 129):

Iterators do not work recursively like that. You have to re-yield each result, by replacing

```python
explore(path)
```

with something like

```python
for value in explore(path):
    yield value
```

[Python 3.3](http://python.org/download/releases/3.3.0/) added the syntax `yield from X`, as proposed in [PEP 380](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/), to serve this purpose. With it you can do this instead:

```python
yield from explore(path)
```

If you're using [generators as coroutines](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/), this syntax also supports the use of [`generator.send()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator.send) to pass values back into the recursively-invoked generators. The simple `for` loop above would not.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer IMHO, as the question is about yield and recursion and not about best way to implement the os.walk ;-) !!! I was breaking my head on this very simple loop... And actually all of the other answers are on the same line...

Comment: Thanks man! Mentioning of 3.3 and iterators specific was really useful.

Comment: As mentioned in this talk at PyCon2014 generators can be used to bypass the recursion limit! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D1twn9kLmYg

Answer (score 37):

The problem is this line of code:

```
explore(path)
```

What does it do?

- calls `explore` with the new `path`
- `explore` runs, creating a generator
- the generator is returned to the spot where `explore(path)` was executed **. . .**
- and is discarded

Why is it discarded?  It wasn't assigned to anything, it wasn't iterated over -- it was completely ignored.

If you want to do something with the results, well, you have to do something with them!  ;)

The easiest way to fix your code is:

```
for name in explore(path):
    yield name
```

When you are confident you understand what's going on, you'll probably want to use `os.walk()` instead.

Once you have migrated to Python 3.3 (assuming all works out as planned) you will be able to use the new `yield from` syntax and the easiest way to fix your code at that point will be:

```
yield from explore(path)
```

Answer (score 8):

Change this:

```
explore(path)
```

To this:

```
for subpath in explore(path):
    yield subpath
```

Or use `os.walk`, as phooji suggested (which is the better option).

Answer (score 3):

That calls `explore` like a function. What you should do is iterate it like a generator:

```
if stat.S_ISDIR(stat_info.st_mode):
  for p in explore(path):
    yield p
else:
  yield path
```

EDIT: Instead of the `stat` module, you could use `os.path.isdir(path)`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
if stat.S_ISDIR(stat_info.st_mode):
    for p in explore(path):
        yield p
```

Answer (score 0):

os.walk is great if you need to traverse all the folders and subfolders. If you don't need that, it's like using an elephant gun to kill a fly.

However, for this specific case, os.walk could be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement the recursion using a stack.

There is not really any advantage in doing this though, other than the fact that it is possible. If you are using python in the first place, the performance gains are probably not worthwhile.

```
import os
import stat

def explore(p):
    '''
    perform a depth first search and yield the path elements in dfs order
        -implement the recursion using a stack because a python can't yield within a nested function call
    '''
    list_t=type(list())
    st=[[p,0]]
    while len(st)>0:
        x=st[-1][0]
        print x
        i=st[-1][1]

        if type(x)==list_t:
            if i>=len(x):
                st.pop(-1)
            else:
                st[-1][1]+=1
                st.append([x[i],0])
        else:
            st.pop(-1)
            stat_info = os.lstat(x)
            if stat.S_ISDIR(stat_info.st_mode):
                st.append([['%s/%s'%(x,a) for a in os.listdir(x)],0])
            else:
                yield x

print list(explore('.'))
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the original question as asked, the key is that the `yield` statement needs to be propagated back out of the recursion (just like, say, `return`).  Here is a working reimplementation of `os.walk()`.  I'm using this in a pseudo-VFS implementation, where I additionally replace `os.listdir()` and similar calls.

```
import os, os.path
def walk (top, topdown=False):
    items = ([], [])
    for name in os.listdir(top):
        isdir = os.path.isdir(os.path.join(top, name))
        items[isdir].append(name)
    result = (top, items[True], items[False])
    if topdown:
        yield result
    for folder in items[True]:
        for item in walk(os.path.join(top, folder), topdown=topdown):
            yield item
    if not topdown:
        yield result
```